# how to create the actual kml file after generating the code?

Tags: java, file, kml, document

I have the code to generate a KML file and everything is fine except the part where I create the actual file. I've read some examples from the internet but I'm getting the same errors in all of them, here's the code I have:

```
    public void crearMapa() {
            try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            kml = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element document = kml.createElement("Document");
            kml.appendChild(document);

            definirConnex(document);
            for(int i = 0; i < a_etnies.size(); i++)
                definirTot(i,document);
            for (Entry<String, Enclavament> entry : a_enclavaments.entrySet())
                colocacio(entry.getValue(),document);

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(kml);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("mapa.kml"));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I've tried another code but I get the same error:

`TRANSFORMER EXCEPTION!javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

In this line:
`transformer.transform(source, result);`

I don't understan why is this happening. Is there any other way of doing this?

EDIT: Code updated to a more clean version. kml is a Document type

Comment: What line do you get NPE?

Comment: in the line I specified `transformer.transform(source, result);`

Comment: Are you catching a `TransformerConfigurationException`, doing nothing useful with it and then continuing as if nothing has gone wrong? Hypothetically, if you were, `transformer` would still be `null`...

Comment: But how can it be null if the code is taken from another example that is supposed to work?
http://crunchify.com/java-simple-way-to-write-xml-dom-file-in-java/